# How can I make a part of text bold in an MS Word table cell?

Tags: c#, ms-word, formatting, cell

I have a C# application which uses an MS Word document. I have tables where some of the text in a cell needs to be **bold**. Is there a way to do it?

Answer (score 1):

I assume you are using Microsoft Office Interop.

The example which I found on:
http://www.c-sharpcorner.com/Forums/ShowMessages.aspx?ThreadID=48632 says:

```
using Microsoft.Office.Interop.Word;

using Microsoft.Office.Core;

Document varDoc = varWord.Documents.Add(ref varMissing, ref varMissing, ref varMissing, ref varTrueValue);

varDoc.Activate();

varDoc.ActiveWindow.ActivePane.View.SeekView = WdSeekView.wdSeekCurrentPageHeader;

varDoc.ActiveWindow.Selection.Font.Bold = 1;
```

Similarly use it in your App.

Else if you are using HTML Tables, then a dirty way is to use

html tags.

Comment: Hi all,
Thanks for the answers. Yes i do use the word interop(11.0.0.0) and i can do write text into a table cell bold or not bold whichever i like . However my problem is part of the text will be bold and part of it not. This is which i couldnt found a solution.